# Return type deduction in recursive function

Tags: c++, c++14

Following code [compiles](http://ideone.com/SlzDnZ) :

```
auto foo(int i) {
  if( i == 1 )
    return i;
  else 
    return foo(i-1)+i ; 
}
```

While following [doesn't](http://ideone.com/QWeLjj), <sub>[***c++1y***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e16c855e9024f7a)</sub>

```
auto foo(int i) {
  return (i == 1) ? i : foo(i-1)+i ;  
}
```

---

Why can't compiler deduce the return type in second case ? Am I missing something over here ?

I know there's a sequence point after `(i == 1)` in second scenario, but that shouldn't be affecting compilation, right ?

Comment: I think in the first case, the compiler deduces the return type from `return i;`, and merely double-checks that the second `return` statement returns the same type. In your second example, that is not possible. But I'm not sure about this, and even if that is what the compiler does, I don't know what the current proposed wording requires.

Comment: If you change the logic of your first example to `i != 1` it won't compile either.

Comment: So adding a `if (false) return int()` would fix the second example? That's a rather surprising effect for unreachable code.

Comment: @MSalters yeah I too [tried](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/068cd12dc17136fe) that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first works because of this rule, 7.1.6.4/11 of the [latest draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf)

> Once a `return` statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type
>   deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other `return` statements.

So the return type is deduced as `int` from the first `return` statement; the second is just checked to make sure that it also gives `int`, assuming that the recursive call does.

The second doesn't compile because the type of the expression depends on the return type; so the type can't be deduced.

Answer (score 7):

A recursive function can have an auto return type only if it has a non-recursive return statement before the recursive call. See [Return type deduction for normal functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html).